# Gnome 3 locks selection no more left click

Tags: selection, mouse-click, gnome3

Hi i have a problem in my Gnome 3 Fedora 15 installation. I've tried both Mesa and nvidia drivers from rpmfusion and the problem persist, so I suppose it is an issue with the desktop manager.
Occasionally, but I'm unable to replicate it, the mouse locks a selection as if I was keeping the left mouse button pressed, which I am not. From that moment on, it is impossible to left click on anything, while middle and right click works properly.
Once it started, the only way I found to stop it is disposing the target of the lock (eg: closing the focused window) but not always is possible (the problems endures even pkill-ing X, because that process will still be alive I imagine).
At last, I can sometimes plug in an usb mouse and have the left click working, while the touchpad will stay locked.
Before submitting a bug, I was curious to know if someone else is experiencing this or if it might be a problem of my setup, as I found no description of this issue googling around.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. What I found was that if I selected something with the left mouse button, it would not "take" until I rolled the mouse pointer over the icon for the task. That is, if I press a link on my Firefox page, Firefox will not go to the link until I move the mouse over the Firefox icon on top of the page.

I find this a pretty bad bug for a major release from somebody as respectable as Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem using Gnome 2.28.2 on Fedora 12 that seemed to appear when I would press numlock.  My mouse would move and I could middle or right click, but never left-click.

I was able to "release" my left mouse button by running:

```
xdotool mouseup 1
```

[xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) is part of the xdotool RPM.

Comment: This is going to be an extremely useful workaround. I'm going to vote up this answer as soon as I see it works. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It seems to be a shell related problem, rather than an input related problem. I mean, the mouse input works (fake or real), but the shell doesn't respond to it

Comment: Looks like we had different problems then :(

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but as I've had this same problem (selection lock and no more left click) for the last two weeks... I found out it happens only when "touchpad clicks" are enabled in

*System Settings >> Mouse and Touchpad >> Touchpad*

So unchecking *"Enable mouseclicks with touchpad"* fixes it, at least in my particular case.